# Should questions using superlatives (best, easiest) always be regarded as subjective?

Tags: discussion, good-questions, scope

We have a few topics ongoing about subjective questions and what is and is not on-topic.

We also have lots of questions coming in that specifically ask for the "best", "easiest", etc?

A couple of superlatives would have definite answers such as "cheapest" but most must depend on the tastes and preferences of each asker and each answerer.

Should we try to tackle this some way before it gets out of hand?

Or should we just ease this aspect of the policy for this SE? Some of these questions and answers are getting plenty of votes.

I've provided an answer below with lists of subjective and nonsubjective questions worded with superlatives. I may have interpreted some differently to you. Please feel free to comment on specific ones offering a better wording if you think they are good questions that need not be subjective.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, the system does *some* checking for this *automatically* - titles containing "best" and a few other words will result in a warning:

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

Of course, folks tend to just ignore this.

If you come across a question with a tile like this, I recommend editing it. See if you can come up with something that captures the *intent* of the asker in a form that can actually be answered with facts and experiences rather than opinions.

Comment: I prefer that we ask the OP to edit his own question. There's less chance of semantic drift and I think it's friendlier. But either way I'd like something closer to a policy and less like the current seemingly arbitrary and polarizing immediate closing or massive upvote.

Comment: @hippietrail: you're free to leave suggestions if you aren't comfortable editing, but I hope you reconsider: good titles are a *huge* asset to any website, both in terms of helping searchers find what they're after and in setting expectations for readers. Whenever you have the time and opportunity to improve a title or tags - even if you can't do anything with the rest of the post - please do so!

Comment: I do edit a lot of tags and I fix some typos or add important words from the body of questions to the question titles but beyond that I prefer to help the newbies by teaching them to help themselves. If I can. But since what's on or off topic seems so fuzzy and unpredictable on our particular SE I don't feel comfortable "being bold" at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should point out in FAQ what users should avoid such superlatives words as `best`, etc. People vote up not because they think question is made according to FAQ but because they think: "Oh, look, I really want to know all of variants about this".

May be we should create community wiki posts (or posts on meta) where we can store all such questions.

Comment: I could link to a few examples if it helps. This seems to be a bigger problem here than in the other sites I've been involved with so it's perhaps the nature of travel questions.

Comment: No, no. I completely agree - it is a problem. I've already flag and comment some of such questions. I think it is only because travel is for everyone, and not many people read the FAQ :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples which look subjective to me - should I flag them as such?

Or can you suggest a less subjective rewording?

- [Best way to get from SeaTac airport to Redmond?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8/best-way-to-get-from-seatac-airport-to-redmond)
- [What is the easiest transportation to use throughout Romania for a foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-easiest-transportation-to-use-throughout-romania-for-a-foreigner)
- [What is the best method for exchanging dollars for Euros?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-is-the-best-method-for-exchanging-dollars-for-euros)
- [Getting the most out of Hotel Loyalty programs? (closed)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/128/getting-the-most-out-of-hotel-loyalty-programs-closed)
- [What are the best things to see in Copenhagen, Denmark?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144/what-are-the-best-things-to-see-in-copenhagen-denmark)
- [Best rates on Domestic US flights online? (closed)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/415/best-rates-on-domestic-us-flights-online-closed)
- [Best way to go from Sepang KLIA to downtown Kuala Lumpur?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/501/best-way-to-go-from-sepang-klia-to-downtown-kuala-lumpur)
- [What are the most effective rideshare sites in the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/676/what-are-the-most-effective-rideshare-sites)
- [What's the easiest way to find a vacation rental?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/733/whats-the-easiest-way-to-find-a-vacation-rental)
- [What time of year is best for taking the Trans-Siberian Express?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/766/what-time-of-year-is-best-for-taking-the-trans-siberian-express)

Here are some examples which use superlatives but are probably not subjective. Agree or disagree?

- [What is the best way to obtain visas for the Trans-Siberian/Trans-Mongolian Railway?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-way-to-obtain-visas-for-the-trans-siberian-trans-mongolian-railw)
- [What are the best ways to avoid data roaming fees when travelling abroad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-are-the-best-ways-to-avoid-data-roaming-fees-when-travelling-abroad)
- [Best time to buy Airline tickets to Shanghai/Hong Kong from USA (Dallas/Fort Worth)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84/best-time-to-buy-airline-tickets-to-shanghai-hong-kong-from-usa-dallas-fort-wort)
- [What times of the year are best for visiting France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-times-of-the-year-are-best-for-visiting-france)
- [When and where do I have the highest chance of seeing auroras?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145/when-and-where-do-i-have-the-highest-chance-at-seeing-a-nice-aurora)
- [What is the safest way to travel from Tehran to North-Pakistan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-is-the-safest-way-to-travel-from-tehran-to-north-pakistan)
- [What's the cheapest way to purchase data access for my verizon smartphone while traveling in Spain?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-purchase-data-access-for-my-verizon-smartphone-while-t)
- [Where would be the optimal place to watch the Nov 2012 Solar Eclipse from?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/210/where-would-be-the-optimal-place-to-watch-the-nov-2012-solar-eclipse-from)
- [What time of the year is the cheapest to cruise in/around North America?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/309/what-time-of-the-year-is-the-cheapest-to-cruise)
- [What's the cheapest transport to get from Ataturk International aiport to the Taksim Square area of Istanbul?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/348/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-get-from-ataturk-international-aiport-to-the-taksim-sq)
- [What's the cheapest way to convert British Pounds into other currency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/403/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-convert-british-pounds-into-other-currency)
- [Which cities in Spain are most unsafe because of thievery? (closed)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/464/which-cities-in-spain-are-most-unsafe-because-of-thievery-closed)
- [Where is the cheapest punt hire in Cambridge?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/475/where-is-the-cheapest-punt-hire-in-cambridge)
- [What is the best time of year to go to Disney World to avoid crowds?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/517/what-is-the-best-time-of-year-to-go-to-disney-world-to-avoid-crowds)
- [Strongest travel sunblock?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/671/strongest-travel-sunblock)

(this is a community wiki so feel free to add to each list)

Comment: Disagree with this: What time of year is best for taking the Trans-Siberian Express? - I think this is very good question, because user asks for help for known route. May be we should rephrase that question.

Comment: I didn't sort the lists by what I felt were good questions but by whether they were worded subjectively by my reading (which wasn't always easy). I'll edit the answer to solicit reworded versions which don't sound subjective.